# Blade select input - selling a selected option

Tags: php, input, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How do I set a certain option as currently selected?

My current code is:

```
{{ Form::select('make',$makes , NULL, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

$makes is an array of car makes.

Lets say the array looks like:

```
[
 0 => 'Audi',
 1 => 'BMW',
 2 => 'Mercedes'
]
```

If I am editing a car, I know that in my DB I have said that car is X make.

In this case, lets say its a BMW. When I create this select input I want BMW to already be shown as the selected option. I have this value already, its just getting the blade input to set it to selected.

I tried:

```
[$tMake->display_name] + $makes
```

But that just add a new option to the list, which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the select the ID you want pre-selected.

You can do this:

```
{{ Form::select('make',$makes , $tMake->id, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

And if you are using validation - you'll want to do something like this, so that the old input is shown if the validation fails

```
{{ Form::select('make',$makes , Input::old('make', $tMake->id), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```